# Does glmmTMB return the standard error for random effect variance components like glmmADMB?

Tags: r

Note:  The following analysis is solely for reproducible objects -- and is not being put forth as a legitimate way to analyze the `bacteria` data from `MASS`.

```
library(glmmADMB)
library(glmmTMB)

data(bacteria,package="MASS")
bacteria$present <- as.numeric(bacteria$y)-1
bacteria$early <- factor(as.numeric(bacteria$week > 3) + 1)
bfit2 <-  glmmadmb(present ~ trt , 
                   random = ~ (1 | ID) + (1 | early),
                   family = "binomial", data = bacteria)
bfit2$S
bfit2$sd_S

bfit3 <- glmmTMB(present ~ trt + (1 | ID) + (1 | early),
                 family = "binomial", data = bacteria)

summary(bfit3)$varcor
confint(bfit3)
```

In my understanding,

- `bfit2$S` contains estimates for the **variance** of random effects for `glmmADMB`
- `bfit3$varcor` contains estimates for the **standard deviation** of random effects for `glmmTMB` (that is, the `sqrt()` of the elements of `bfit2$S`)
- `bfit2$sd_S` contains **standard errors** of  the estimates in `bfit2$S` for `glmmADMB` (as noted in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20224717/2727349))

Where are the **standard errors** for `bfit3$varcor` stored in a `glmmTMB` object?  **UPDATE**:  `confint` is implemented for glmmTMB objects, so if calculating 95% CI is the end goal then that's available ([Thanks kaskr](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/280#issuecomment-353346037)).

```
> bfit2$S
$ID
            (Intercept)
(Intercept)      1.4047

$early
            (Intercept)
(Intercept)     0.51465

> bfit2$sd_S
$ID
            (Intercept)
(Intercept)     0.94743

$early
            (Intercept)
(Intercept)     0.61533

> summary(bfit3)$varcor

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Std.Dev.
 ID     (Intercept) 1.18513 
 early  (Intercept) 0.71733 
> confint(bfit3)
                                    2.5 %     97.5 %   Estimate
cond.(Intercept)                1.1934429  4.1351114  2.6642771
cond.trtdrug                   -2.6375284 -0.0503639 -1.3439462
cond.trtdrug+                  -2.0819454  0.5325683 -0.7746885
cond.Std.Dev.ID.(Intercept)     0.6118984  2.2953603  1.1851276
cond.Std.Dev.early.(Intercept)  0.2222685  2.3150437  0.7173293
```

As we can see, `sqrt(1.4047) =  1.18513` and `sqrt(0.51465) =  0.71733` so that indicates `bfit2$S` gives the estimates for the variances and `summary(bfit3)$varcor` gives the estimates for the standard deviation.

**2nd update**:

After some digging, I realized that `bfit3$sdr` returns the variance components on the log-sd-scale, along with the standard errors. So one thought was to avoid `confint` and back calculate the SEs by calculating 95%CIs on log-sd-scale and then transforming to desired scale and then dividing width of CI by 2*1.96.

```
## to get the standard errors from glmmTMB:
bfit3$sdr
## note that theta is just log(sd)
exp(summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[4,1])
exp(summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[5,1])
## calculate the (wald) lower and upper on the log(sd) scale:
low.log.sd.id    <- summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[4,1] - 1.96*summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[4,2]
low.log.sd.early <- summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[5,1] - 1.96*summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[5,2]
upp.log.sd.id    <- summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[4,1] + 1.96*summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[4,2]
upp.log.sd.early <- summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[5,1] + 1.96*summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[5,2]
## convert to variance scale by taking exp and then squaring
low.var.id <- exp(low.log.sd.id)^2
upp.var.id <- exp(upp.log.sd.id)^2
low.var.early <- exp(low.log.sd.early)^2
upp.var.early <- exp(upp.log.sd.early)^2
## back calculate SEs
(upp.var.id - low.var.id) / (2*1.96)
(upp.var.early - low.var.early) / (2*1.96)
## see how they compare to the confint answers for sd:
sqrt(c(low.var.id, upp.var.id))
sqrt(c(low.var.early, upp.var.early))
```

Run it:

```
> ## to get the standard errors from glmmTMB:
> bfit3$sdr
sdreport(.) result
        Estimate Std. Error
beta   2.6642771  0.7504394
beta  -1.3439462  0.6600031
beta  -0.7746885  0.6669800
theta  0.1698504  0.3372712
theta -0.3322203  0.5977910
Maximum gradient component: 4.83237e-06 
> ## note that theta is just log(sd)
> exp(summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[4,1])
[1] 1.185128
> exp(summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[5,1])
[1] 0.7173293
> ## calculate the (wald) lower and upper on the log(sd) scale:
> low.log.sd.id    <- summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[4,1] - 1.96*summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[4,2]
> low.log.sd.early <- summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[5,1] - 1.96*summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[5,2]
> upp.log.sd.id    <- summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[4,1] + 1.96*summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[4,2]
> upp.log.sd.early <- summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[5,1] + 1.96*summary(bfit3$sdr, "fixed")[5,2]
> ## convert to variance scale by taking exp and then squaring
> low.var.id <- exp(low.log.sd.id)^2
> upp.var.id <- exp(upp.log.sd.id)^2
> low.var.early <- exp(low.log.sd.early)^2
> upp.var.early <- exp(upp.log.sd.early)^2
> ## back calculate SEs
> (upp.var.id - low.var.id) / (2*1.96)
[1] 1.24857
> (upp.var.early - low.var.early) / (2*1.96)
[1] 1.354657
> ## see how they compare to the confint answers for sd:
> sqrt(c(low.var.id, upp.var.id))
[1] 0.611891 2.295388
> sqrt(c(low.var.early, upp.var.early))
[1] 0.2222637 2.3150935
```

The last two rows above match the last two rows of the confint(bfit3) output pretty well.  Now I guess I just wonder why the SEs for glmmADMB were 0.94743 and 0.61533 whereas the back-calculated ones for glmmTMB are 1.24857 and 1.354657 respectively...(?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure about your analysis, but here's what I did to check (including digging in the guts of `glmmADMB` and using slightly obscure aspects of `glmmTMB`):

- run `glmmADMB`, and dig into the ADMB `.std` output file to check on the results:

> n   par        estimate   sd        
>   4   tmpL       1.6985e-01 3.3727e-01 
>   5   tmpL      -3.2901e-01 5.9780e-01 
>   ... 
>   62   S          1.4045     9.474e-01 
>   63   S          5.178e-01  6.191e-01

These lines are, respectively, the internal parameters (`tmpL`: log-standard deviations) and the transformed parameters (variances).

Re-do the transformation and check:

```
tmpL <-    c(0.16985,-0.32901)
cbind(admb.raw=exp(2*tmpL),
      admb=unlist(bfit2$S),
      tmb =unlist(VarCorr(bfit3)))
##        admb.raw    admb       tmb
## ID    1.4045262 1.40450 1.4045274
## early 0.5178757 0.51788 0.5145613
```

We get from the standard deviation of the log-std dev of the random effect to the standard deviation of the variance by multiplying by the derivative of the transformation (V = exp(2*logsd), so dV/d(logsd) = 2*exp(2*logsd))

```
## sd of log-sd from glmmTMB
tmb_sd <- sqrt(diag(vcov(bfit3,full=TRUE)))[4:5]
tmb_logsd <- bfit3$sdr$par.fixed[4:5]
tmpL_sd <- c(0.33727,0.5978)
cbind(admb.raw=tmpL_sd*2*exp(2*tmpL),
      admb=unlist(bfit2$sd_S),
      tmb=tmb_sd*2*exp(2*tmb_logsd))
##        admb.raw    admb       tmb
## ID    0.9474091 0.94741 0.9474132
## early 0.6191722 0.61918 0.6152003
```

So these all seem to match up OK.

Answer (score 0):

The `$varcor` object is a list. The standard deviations are stored as attributes:

```
str( summary(bfit3)$varcor )
List of 2
 $ cond:List of 2
  ..$ ID   : num [1, 1] 1.4
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "(Intercept)"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "(Intercept)"
  .. ..- attr(*, "stddev")= Named num 1.19
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "(Intercept)"
  .. ..- attr(*, "correlation")= num [1, 1] 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "(Intercept)"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "(Intercept)"
  .. ..- attr(*, "blockCode")= Named num 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "us"
  ..$ early: num [1, 1] 0.515
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "(Intercept)"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "(Intercept)"
  .. ..- attr(*, "stddev")= Named num 0.717
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "(Intercept)"
  .. ..- attr(*, "correlation")= num [1, 1] 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "(Intercept)"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "(Intercept)"
  .. ..- attr(*, "blockCode")= Named num 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "us"
  ..- attr(*, "sc")= num 1
  ..- attr(*, "useSc")= logi FALSE
 $ zi  : NULL
 - attr(*, "sc")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "VarCorr.glmmTMB"
```

This will loop over the `.$cond` elements of that object:

```
sapply( summary(bfit3)$varcor$cond, function(x) attr( x, "stddev") )
   ID.(Intercept) early.(Intercept) 
        1.1851276         0.7173293
```

Comment: This answer provides the standard deviations, which are already displayed in the question as `summary(bfit3)$varcor` -- I was seeking the standard **errors** of these estimates.

Comment: I think there may be some terminology confusion at play here. The term "standard error of the estimate" is the standard deviation of a parameter estimate (in "parameter space"). The "standard error" and the "standard deviation" are different by a factor of sqrt(df) when view together in the original scale of the data.

Comment: We might try paging @BenBolker to get an expert independent opinion on this matter and on my use of terminology.

Comment: Good idea!  I posted an issue to the glmmTMB github page and they brought to my attention `confint()` and I updated my question accordingly.  I suppose I'm comfortable getting the intended SEs - now my question has evolved to why the are different between glmmADMB and glmmTMB.